# Drawing a graph with dashed line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wanted to draw a graph like this

[image]

but I got this

[image]

Which I consider very good as I'm just a beginner, now I need to know how to put the dashed line and the point of interest on the graphs and how to make the lines thicker.
Thank you for your help and time.
the code I wrote is

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = center, 
        xmin=0,
        xmax=40,
        ymin=-12,
        ymax=5,
        xlabel = $t$,
        ylabel = {$a_y$},]

    \addplot [domain=0:21.6, ]
    {2.25};
    \addplot [domain=21.6:38, ]
    {-9.8};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\addplot [domain=-9.8:2.25,dashed]
   (21.6,x);`

Comment: Please post compilable code rather than fragments - it is much easier to help with a complete minimal example.

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities to achieve what you want, but an "efficient" solution would depend on the *real* problem. So if you have presented a real world example, i.e. only two horizontal lines which need to be "connected" by one vertical line, probably the answer given in [marmot's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436934/d#comment1096239_436934) is most most efficient one. If you would need to connect e.g. 100 horizontal lines, I think there are better ways to do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.